# Function for converting columns of a data frame into key value pairs

Tags: pandas, list, dictionary, iteration, key

I have a dataframe (these are just sample columns for reference, the actual number of columns is quite large)

| id | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 24 | 98 | 74 | 32 |
| 456 | 65 | 90 | 61 | 96 |

I would like to convert it into a data where id is the first column and second column contains values where column 1 values  is used as key and column 2 values are used as value to create key value pair for example row 1  and row 2 will look like this with col name

| id | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | [{24:98},{74:32}] |
| 456 | [{65:90},{ 61: 96}] |

what I did I took id as is and used column 1 values  is used as key and column 2 values are used as value to create key value pair, then used column 3 values  is used as key and column 4 values are used as value to create key value pair and then merged them in to a single list.

I'm trying the below solution but getting **TypeError (unhashable type: 'list')
**

result_list = []

for _, row in df.iterrows():
current_id = row['id']

```
# Create a list of dictionaries for each row
key_value_pairs = [{row[i]: row[i + 1]} for i in range(1, len(row), 2)]

# Append the ID and list of dictionaries to the result list
result_list.append((current_id, key_value_pairs))
```

result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_list, columns=['id', 'col1'])

Answer (score 0):

Use nested list comprehension for expected ouput with remove `id` column and select pair and unpair items in next columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [123, 456], 
                   'A': [24, 65], 
                   'B': [98, 90], 
                   'C': [74, 61], 
                   'D': [32, 96]})

L = [[{a:b} for a, b in zip(r[::2], r[1::2])] for r in df.drop('id',axis=1).to_numpy()]

result_df = df[['id']].assign(col1=L)
print (result_df)
    id                  col1
0  123  [{24: 98}, {74: 32}]
1  456  [{65: 90}, {61: 96}]
```

Comment: Tried this, still getting TypeError (unhashable type: 'list')

Comment: @AnushaPal - Instead your solution from `result_list = []` to `result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_list, columns=['id', 'col1'])` is used my answer?

Comment: @AnushaPal - Added sample data for testing

Comment: this code is working on the sample dataset shared above but on the original dataset which has approx 33k rows and 2207 columns the code is throwing the error
there are NaN as well as blank values in the dataframe, can these impact the result?

Comment: @AnushaPal - Can you test if input data are without lists? `print (df.loc[:, df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)).any()])` return columns with at least one list

Comment: now the code is working after dropping a few unnecessary columns, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Data can have even and odd numbers of columns. Written code that should cover any number of columns.
Step 1: Create a data frame

```
import pandas as pd
actual_df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [123, 456], 
                   'A': [24, 65], 
                   'B': [98, 90], 
                   'C': [74, 61], 
                   'D': [32, 96],
                   'E': [36, 66]})
```

step 2: Convert data frame into NumPy array
Step 3: Iterate over each column and rows
Step 4: Check for the position of the last column, if it is less than the count of the column, fill 'NA' as the value.

```
result_dict = {}
for row in actual_df.to_numpy():
    row_list = []
    for i in range(1, len(row),2):
        if len(row) > i+1:
            row_list.append({row[i]:row[i+1]})
        else:
            row_list.append({row[i]:'NA'})
    result_dict[row[0]] = row_list
```

Step 5: Store id as the key and list of column data as the value in the result dictionary.
Step 6: Create a result data frame, store keys in id and values in the col1 columns.

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'col1'])
result_df['id'] = result_dict.keys()
result_df['col1'] = result_dict.values()
```

I hope this will help you, feel free to provide suggestions.